# How to make validating form entries easier?

Tags: jquery-plugins, validation

I need a jQuery plugin which can really save the pandas,

which one will you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

This one: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/
Demo is here: http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/